# How to make maven put resource files of a dependancy in parent war and not dependancy jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have two projects A and B.
B is dependant on A.

A has some resource files.

When using `mvn install` on B, it uses the resources that were packaged in A.jar (as that was built previously)
I would like the resources to be packaged in B so I could edit them easily. (Especially since B is deployed as WAR)

Copying the resources to project B might not help since the code in A uses the following to retrieve info

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/resourceFile.properties");
```

do I need to change the path to relate to project B? if so  how should one do it?

What is the best approach for handling this?

Comment: _"When using mvn install on A, the resources are packaged in B.jar I would like the resources to be packaged in A so I could edit them easily. (Especially since B is deployed as WAR)"_ - something is wrong with this statement?

Comment: resourceFile.properties goes into B.jar, while I would like to have it directly in WEB-INF\classes so I could edit it them easily

Comment: If you run `mvn install` on project `A`, how would a resource in that project end up in `B.war`? Why would `A` even know about `B` at that point? It's a bit confusing. Maybe this sounds right - _"When using `mvn install` on `A`, the resources are packaged in `A.jar`; I would instead like the resources to be packaged in `B` so I could edit them easily. (Especially since B is deployed as WAR)"_?

Comment: Please think clearly about what you are asking and rephrase your question, we cant help you if we dont know what you're asking!

Comment: @mystarrocks thank you. Edited. deeply sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The question is still vague - running `mvn install` on `B` does not result in the resource getting packaged inside `A` - it's b/c you previously ran `mvn install` on `A` and had it packaged and installed to the repo and when you ran the install on `B`, it merely pulled the `A`.jar dependency from the repo. Anyway I'll try to ansswer the question now that I understand your problem.

Comment: you are right that A got built before. Thought that was obvious when u have a dependency. Anyway, edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I've found
it to add this to your B project POM

```
<build>
....
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>../A/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>

        </resources>
... 
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `maven-shade-plugin`'s [`shade` mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html) to repackage select artifacts from your project `A` into `B`. I haven't entirely looked at the [`jarjar-maven-plugin`](http://sonatype.github.io/jarjar-maven-plugin/), but it could also assist you in doing that.

Look at the ["Relocating classes" section](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) of the `shade` plugin documentation in particular to understand how to do it. It should work equally well with resource files in theory.

Your code will work as it always does - it does not matter whether the resource being loaded is in the same jar or in a different jar in the `B`'s classpath or inside `B`'s `WEB-INF/lib` as long as it's in the classpath and referred by the right path in your code.

It's good that you didn't consider moving the property file into `B` project's codebase - had you done that, `A` would no longer be self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

As long as project B is in the same classpath as project A, that code will continue to work.

It may be clearer, however, to use [ClassLoader.getResoucreAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) rather than [Class.getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-). The method on `Class` by default looks for resources relative to the package name of the `Class`. You have provided an absolute path (leading '/'), indicating that the package relative logic is not needed.